# Counting Dashes to Exit a While Loop in C

Tags: c

I made a hangman game using a while loop. I want to use the number of dashes == 0 to break the loop so the player knows that they won. The word is hidden behind "-"s. My word is coding, so it has 6 dashes.

When I run the program, the first guess at the word is an accurate number of dashes. But after the second guess, and so on, it is adding all of the dashes from all the guesses together, not just from that one turn. By the third turn it says I have 9 dashes because that's how many is left over in all of the turns.  Any ideas on how to fix?

```
char word[] = { "Coding" };
char dash[] = {"------"};
char guess;

int numguesses = 10; 
int count;
int loopcount;
int i;
int dashcount;

int main()
{
printf("Your Word Is: %s", &dash);
//printf("\nWord: %c", &dash);

loopcount = 10;
count = 1;
while (count <= loopcount)
{
    printf("\n\nPick a letter to guess: ");
    scanf(" %c", &guess);

    printf("\n\nYour Guess Was %c. ", guess);
    count = count + 1;

    if (guess == 'c')
    {
        dash[0] = 'c';
        printf("\n\n %s", dash);
    }
    else if (guess == 'o')
    {
        dash[1] = 'o';
        printf("\n\n %s", dash);
    }
    else if (guess == 'd')
    {
        dash[2] = 'd';
        printf("\n\n %s", dash);
    }
    else if (guess == 'i')
    {
        dash[3] = 'i';
        printf("\n\n %s", dash);
    }
    else if (guess == 'n')
    {
        dash[4] = 'n';
        printf("\n\n %s", dash);
    }
    else if (guess == 'g')
    {
        dash[5] = 'g';
        printf("\n\n %s", dash);
    }
    else
        printf("That Letter Is Not Apart of this Word");
    
    printf("\n\nYou are at Guess Number %d, Your word is at %s", count, dash);
    
    for (i = 0; dash[i]; i++)
    {
        if (dash[i] == '-')
        {
            dashcount++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nDoes it work ?: %d", dashcount);
}

if (count < numguesses)
{
    printf("\n\n\nYou Won the Game, Your Awesome!!");
}
else
{
    printf("\n\n\nI'm Sorry, the word was %s.", word);
}

printf("\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("Your Word Is: %s", &dash);` read the manual.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh What manual?

Comment: `printf()`  manual, and note the types!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not resetting the `dashcount` variable, so every time it starts with previous value and adds the dashes left

```
for (i = 0; dash[i]; i++)
{
    if (dash[i] == '-')
    {
        dashcount++;
    }
}
```

You can easily fix this in this way

```
dashcount=0;
for (i = 0; dash[i]; i++)
{
    if (dash[i] == '-')
    {
        dashcount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!